# HTTP Response for filtered messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm new to Spring and Spring integration, and I've decided to jump in with both feet - now, I'm stuck.

Consider the following Spring configuration - an inbound-gateway that sends requests to an AMQP broker for processing:

```
<int:channel id="requestChannel" />
<int:channel id="responseChannel"/>
<int:channel id="myDiscardChannel"/>
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="myInboundGateway" 
                            request-channel="requestChannel"
                            reply-channel="responseChannel"
                            mapped-request-headers="*"
                            mapped-response-headers="Return-Status, Return-Status-Msg, HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS"       
                            path="/foo"
                            reply-timeout="50000"/>

<int:chain input-channel="requestChannel" output-channel="responseChannel">
    <int:filter expression="someExpression" discard-channel="myDiscardChannel" />
    <int-amqp:outbound-gateway amqp-template="amqpTemplate" exchange-name-expression="fooexchange" reply-timeout="50000" />
</int:chain>
```

What I would like to be able to do is when the contrived "someExpression" expression  evaulates false for the message that represents the HTTP request, complete the original request with an appropriate HTTP status code and payload.

I've looked a couple of approaches:

1) Setting the filter to generate exceptions, and processing them on an error-channel, but I cannot seem to get this right - a proper example of this technique has been hard to find.

2) Setting the filter to send discarded messages to a discard channel - I've not yet figured out how to generate and send a message back to the inbound-gateway that will complete the original request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply subscribe a transformer to the discard channel; omit the output-channel on the transformer and the transformed result will go back to the inbound gateway.

You can remove the `responseChannel` (reply-channel) from the inbound gateway and chain (output-channel); it is not needed in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks Gary - it was indeed "just that easy!".